# Standardize species richness by elevation

Tags: regression, data-transformation, normalization, glmm, ecology

I am studying the effect of forest structure on recruitment. One of the variables is species richness defined as the number of species.

The aim is to quantify the effect of species richness on recruitment by using a glmm. But I want to avoid obtaining a variable which reflects an elevational gradient instead of species richness. The correlation between elevation and species richness makes this difficult.

The model also includes precipitation and temperature-related variables. Degree day sum, water balance and soil information to be more precise. Is this sufficient to account for the elevation? Or how do I know if my precipitation and temperature variables are good enough? I am unsure if I should scale the variable for species richness by elevation.

So far I use z-transformation for every 500 m of elevation.

But I couldn't find any literature on similar problems. Is there a general way to normalize/standardize a variable that is correlated with another variable?

Comment: How strong is the correlation between species richness and elevation? What is the r? You could try calculating variance inflation factors, to investigate how much any collinearity affects the model.

Comment: correlation is -0.57. VIF is below 2 for all variables except degree day sum which has 3.7.

Comment: Why wouldn't you include both richness and elevation in the model?

Comment: Because I am interested in the effect of species richness and environmental variables which are mostly correlated with elevation.

Comment: Putting elevation in the model will give you an estimate for the effect of species richness that takes into account that elevation may also play a role. This is not without its problems (the data cannot perfectly tell apart influences of strongly correlated variables), but seems better to me than leaving elevation out of the model. Whether your way of taking into account elevation is even better is very hard to tell, because it depends on how exactly elevation and richness are related, also from the subject matter perspective.

Comment: I think it´s a bad idea to use elevation along with degree day sum in the model. These variables are strongly correlated (0.96). VIFs also suggests using degree day sum over elevation. Anyway, I think that the choice of variables is not the problem. I want to calculate a variable which quantifies the standardized effect of species richness on recruitment. The thought behind this is, that at very high altitudes the highest possbile number of species is much lower than at lower altitudes, which might lead to an underestimation of species richness effects on sites on high elevation.

Comment: VIFs are not a method to decide which variables to use, however I'd agree that having two variables in a model with correlation 0.96 is not a good idea. Now this suggests that degree day sum and other variables may already pretty much account for the effect of elevation, and your transformation may not be needed. Ultimately it's an interesting question but hard to comment on without seeing the data and knowing all the details (which is one reason why you won't find any "standard solution" in the literature).